# Numpy: averaging many datapoints at each time step

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

This question is probably answered somewhere, but I cannot find where, so I will ask here:

I have a set of data consisting of several samples per timestep. So, I basically have two arrays, "times", which looks something like: (0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,...) and my data which is the value for each time. Each timestep has a random number of samples. I would like to get the average value of the data at each timestep in an efficient manner.

I have prepared the following sample code to show what my data looks like. Basically, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to write the "average_values" function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def average_values(x,y):
    unique_x = np.unique(x)
    averaged_y = [np.mean(y[x==ux]) for ux in unique_x]
    return unique_x, averaged_y

#generate our data
times   = []
samples = []

#we have some timesteps:
for time in np.linspace(0,10,101):

    #and a random number of samples at each timestep:
    num_samples = np.random.random_integers(1,10)

    for i in range(0,num_samples):
        times.append(time)
        samples.append(np.sin(time)+np.random.random()*0.5)

times   = np.array(times)
samples = np.array(samples)

plt.plot(times,samples,'bo',ms=3,mec=None,alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(*average_values(times,samples),color='r')
plt.show()
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I propose a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) solution. It is highly recommended if you are going to be working with time series.

### Create test data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = np.random.randint(0,10,size=50)
values = np.sin(times) + np.random.random_sample((len(times),))
s = pd.Series(values, index=times)
s.plot(linestyle='.', marker='o')
```

[image]

### Calculate averages

```
avs = s.groupby(level=0).mean()
avs.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution! I must get to know Pandas better - it seems like it always hold the solution to my problems. Small question: how do I extract the "unique_x" and "averaged_y" from the avs object?

Comment: That would be `avs.index`, and `avs.values`.

Answer (score 9):

A generic code to do this would do something as follows:

```
def average_values_bis(x, y):
    unq_x, idx = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    count_x = np.bincount(idx)
    sum_y = np.bincount(idx, weights=y)

    return unq_x, sum_y / count_x
```

Adding the function above and following line for the plotting to your script

```
plt.plot(*average_values_bis(times, samples),color='g')
```

produces this output, with the red line hidden behind the green one:

[image]

But timing both approaches reveals the benefits of using `bincount`, a 30x speed-up:

```
%timeit average_values(times, samples)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.83 ms per loop

%timeit average_values_bis(times, samples)
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.9 us per loop
```

Comment: Wow! This is way faster. I am getting closer to 200x faster on my system. Depending on how many timesteps I use and how many points per timestep, this is also faster than the pandas approach, though I find that one a little easier to understand. Thanks!